# How to Render React App in Custom HTML5 Element instead div[id=root]

Tags: reactjs

I am at requirement that I have build some ReactJs components but need to use them inside Custom HTML tags( just like normal tags )

I am trying to create a "Board" component which just displays a text "In board...". Now I am trying to use this in my HTML page as .

My board.js file:

```
class Board extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <div className="status"> In board.... </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My HTML page:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="board.js" type="text/babel"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <Board />
        </body>
</html>
```

tag must be treated like an HTML tag and should load React component and display the text "In board....".

Comment: Any reason why you can't write, `ReactDOM.render(<Board />, ...)` ? The only way to do this is by wrapping your react components in Web Components which also require you to call ReactDOM at the end of the day. https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html#using-react-in-your-web-components

Comment: You've put this component to html via `ReactDOM.render`. So you can create `div` with `id="root"` for example in your `html`, and in `React` add something like: `ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Comment: I can use  "ReactDOM.render..." and in html "<div id="root"></div>". But I want to create a pure custom element where in HTML page, we should be in a position use this component like an HTML tag.

Comment: you should use ReactDOM.render and in order to create element use JS Method - customElements.define(name, constructor, options);
Check my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have to create using `customElements` API. You can use [`customElements.define`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) Method to create your own but name should be hyphen separated.

```
window.customElements.define('message-board',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.innerHTML = '';
    }
  }
);
```

Below is the Working Example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Board </title>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          window.customElements.define('message-board',
            class extends HTMLElement {
              constructor() {
                super();

                this.innerHTML = '';
              }
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/babel">
          class Board extends React.Component {

            render() {

              return (
                <div>
                  <div className="status"> In board.... </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
          }

            ReactDOM.render(
                <Board />,
                document.getElementsByTagName('message-board')[0]
            );
        </script>
        <script>
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <message-board />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when we have multiple "<message-board>" tags this won't work as it is working on getElementsByTagName('message-board')[0]. Here there is no significance of custom element creation  window.customElements.define('message-board',
            class extends HTMLElement {
              constructor() {
                super();

                this.innerHTML = '';
              }
            }); as used  ReactDOM.render(
                <Board />,
                document.getElementsByTagName('message-board')[0]
            );

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom element and rendering React component to this custom element can be done as below. Assuming "Board" is an React component.

```
window.customElements.define('message-board',
    class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();

      }

  connectedCallback() {

          ReactDOM.render(<Board />, this);

        }

    });
```

**A working solution to convert a simple React component to HTML Custom element**

```html
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Board </title>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.0.3/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script >
   <script type="text/babel">
      class Board extends React.Component {
      
        render() {
      
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="status"> In board.... </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
       
      window.customElements.define('message-board',
        class extends HTMLElement {
          constructor() {
            super();
      
          }
      
      connectedCallback() {
      
              ReactDOM.render(<Board />, this);
      
            }
      
        });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
      <message-board  />
   </div>
   <div>
      <message-board  />
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```